# Not able to trace database requests with spring boot 3 and Micrometer

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry, micrometer

I have used the following maven dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-registry-otlp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
                <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.ttddyy.observation</groupId>
                <artifactId>datasource-micrometer-spring-boot</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

and following Otel config:

```java
    @Configuration
    public class OtelConfiguration {
        @Bean
        OtlpHttpSpanExporter otlpHttpSpanExporter() {
            return OtlpHttpSpanExporter.builder()
                    .setEndpoint("http://localhost:4318/v1/traces")
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

I am able to see REST API traces in Jaeger but not able to see any database (Mongo, Postgres and Redis) traces, but if I use open telemetry jar, everything works as expected.

```
     java -javaagent:"/opt/eltropy/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar" -Dotel.service.name=rakesh-test  -jar /Users/rakesh/.m2/repository/com/radiant/eltropy/test-app/1.0.0/test-app-1.0.0.jar
```

Comment: the recommendation from the opentelemetry side would be to remove micrometer tracing and use opentelemetry tracing directly, along with the "library" (non-javaagent) instrumentations that opentelemetry provides: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/supported-libraries.md#libraries--frameworks

Comment: Thanks @trask. I am able to instrument Postgres and Mongodb. Looks like Redis instrumentation is not available without using a Java agent?

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is instrumented, these are the dependencies you need:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'net.ttddyy.observation:datasource-micrometer-spring-boot:1.+'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-otlp'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'
```

We have a sample that uses `JdbcTemplate`: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-samples/tree/main/micrometer-samples-boot3-database

And I have a demo app which uses JPA: https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/teahouse/

Comment: How does r2dbc support?

Comment: The question was about jdbc, see: `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` but r2dbc is also instrumented, please see their docs.